# Messages are not flowing from a Automatic activity to next manual decision activity + Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, automatic-activity

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1

I have a Automatic Activity which publishes bundle to server. I have written below code in ActivityFinishData.

```
 ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData()
        {
            Message = "I am coming from Step 1",
            NextAssignee = new LinkToTrusteeData()
            {
                IdRef = user.Id,
                Title = "Content Author"
            }
        };


  CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, finishData, new ReadOptions());
```

Now next activity is a Manual Decision Activity . But I am not able to see the previous message in Tridion interface for activities .

I have made a four step workflow .. first two are manual activity and message are passed nicely and shown in previous workflow activity box also. Third activity i have written below line of code but this message is not flowing to fourth activity. What is going wrong here.

```
ActivityFinishData finishData = new ActivityFinishData()
    {
        Message = "I am coming from Step 3"            
    };

CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, finishData, new ReadOptions());
```

[image]

Can anybody please suggest what is going wrong here .

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am going to open a ticket to Tridion on this and see what they say.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `DecisionActivityFinishData` instead of `ActivityFinishData`

```
DecisionActivityFinishData finishData = new DecisionActivityFinishData()
        {
            Message = "I am coming from Step 1",
            NextAssignee = new LinkToTrusteeData()
            {
                IdRef = user.Id,
                Title = "Content Author"
            }
        };

CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, finishData, new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: No DecisionActivityFinishData  is not working also...

Comment: any undate on this.